# R cannot find the function get_map

Tags: windows, r, google-maps, dictionary, plot

I'm trying to make a google map with R, with this `r_google_maps.r` script:

```
require(ggmap)

mapImageData1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -0.016179, lat = 51.538525),
    color = "color",
    source = "google",
    maptype = "satellite",
    zoom = 17)

ggmap(mapImageData1,
    extent = "device",
    ylab = "Latitude",
    xlab = "Longitude")
```

and I call `source("r_google_maps.r");` in the command window,

I get this error :

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "get_map"

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks !

### Edit:

I'm on windows 7 64-bit

Comment: do you have `ggmap` installed?

Comment: I tried calling require(ggmap)  and library(ggmap), but I don't know. How do I make sure I have it installed ?

Comment: if it doesn't load, you dont have it. `ggmap` is on cran, so just `install.packages('ggmap')`

Comment: This is a fairly decent idiom to use to test for existence of and then install a package if it's not there: `if ("ggmap" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE) { install.packages("ggmap") }`. You'll still need a `require(ggmap)` or `library(ggmap)` after that. The `get_map` error you're encountering is indicative of not having the `ggmap` package loaded as suggested by [@rawr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what platform you are on, but for me to get 'ggmap' properly installed on Linux, I had to install the OS package libpng-devel, THEN upgrade the 'maps' R package by reinstalling.

Then mapproj and ggmap installed without further errors, and I successfully saw the map you were loading in my RStudio window.

Perhaps you can check any error messages that might have gone by when you tried to install ggmap for any clues that are particular to your platform and environment.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I'm trying this on Windows 7. Any suggestions for Windows ?